# AngularJS html5mode with Nginx (resources interrupted) for images and fonts

Tags: angularjs, nginx

We are working to setup AngularJS app with html5mode behind nginx web server, for the most parts we were able to achieve that, pages are loading fine, URL mapping as well as css and any images referenced via css.

Yet, all fonts and direct references images are failing to load (e.g `src="/images/myimage.jpg"`)

And this issue is only happening on the web server, not when serving the AngularJS app in developer machine.

Below is how our nginx configuration looks like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    root /var/lib/www/dist;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        root /var/lib/www/dist;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /var/lib/app/etc/templates;
    }

}
```

The images and fonts are not loading and in console showing below error

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/images/Er.jpg".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/images/Ka.jpg".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-regular.woff".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-bold.woff".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-light.woff".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-regular.ttf".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-bold.ttf".
about:1 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://staging.com/styles/fonts/proximanova/proximanova-light.ttf".
```